# Laravel - Eloquent Relationships (Query made; Not fetching value)

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to get some database information, and I can see the query is being done, but I am unable to come up with content... I have the follows:

```
class Vendor extends Eloquent {
    public function spider()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Spider');
    }
}

class Spider extends Eloquent {
 public function report()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Report');
    }
}
```

So... now I am trying to use it as:

```
$vendor = Vendor::find(1);
$vendor->spider->report->id;
```

This is not giving me any result - the id is not being fetched. However, I can tell a correct query is being made to the database...

```
select * from `report` where `report`.`spider_id` = ?
```

Why is it not giving me anything? I have tried several ways such as... `$vendor->spider->first()->report->first()->id`... and so on... but all I get is errors.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Report is of type *hasMany* so a Collection will be retrieved. Process that Collection to find the instance you want.